Limit with sequence. How to "try them all"?
I don't understand how to operate when I have to deal with limits of function by using sequences. We have studies this theorem that says that $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ exists if by choosing any sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n \to x_0$ as $n \to +\infty$, and $a_n \neq x_0$, and $f(a_n)$ is well defined, then $\lim_{n\to +\infty} f(a_n)$ exists it is independent from the chosen sequence.
We made an example with $\lim_{x\to +\infty} \sin(x)$, noticing that $a_n = \pi n$ and $b_n = \frac{\pi}{2}n$ give respectively $0$ and $\pm 1$ as limits, hence the limit doesn't exist.
Now my question is the following:

Assuming I want to use this for calculating a trivial limit like $\lim_{x\to +\infty} e^{-x}$ which goes to zero. I can choose $a_n = n$, or $b_n = e^n$ and so on. There are infinitely many sequences I can choose. But how would I proceed? I cannot try them all of course. How can I be sure, for a given function, that the limit will exist without having to try "all" the sequences?

Thank you!

Choosing a sequence helps to disprove limit doesnt exist. By choosing one sequence we can't say limit exists (lim $e^-x$as x tends to infinity)

@Guruprasad I know, but then how would I use that theorem? You mean that I would use it only with problematic functions? I find it hard to believe, since it's a theorem and in some manner it should tell me that $\lim_{x\to +\infty} e^{-x}$ always exists and it's always zero for any good sequence I choose...

I mean, that theorem helps to prove limit doesn't exist(to prove it we need to choose two sequences ).in my 1st comment there is a typo(disprove× that is prove).

We can't  try infinitely many sequences (it is a waste of time)

To choose better sequences for limits, we need to understand behavior of functions

Take a simpler example:
We prove the following proposition:

For every real number $x$ we have $\displaystyle\frac{x^2+1}{2}\ge x$.


Proof: Let $x\in\Bbb R$. Since $(x-1)^2\ge 0$, we have $x^2-2x+1\ge 0$, then $x^2+1\ge 2x$ and finally $\displaystyle\frac{x^2+1}{2}\ge x$.

We didn't prove the proposition trying with each real number. Instead we took a "generic" real number $x$ and prove the proposition for it. Since we didn't make any particular assumption about that number we ended giving a proof that works for all real numbers.
The same thing happens with the sequences. In your example, you don't try with each sequence.
You say: "Let $a_n$ any sequence that converges to $\infty$". You're considering a generic sequence converging to $\infty$. Then you proceed to prove that $e^{-a_n}$ tends to $0$.

Ok I understand the concept but what about functions for which the limit doesn't exist? Maybe there is a very specific sequence, rather than the usual ones, that I have to try, but I cannot know a priori (except, of course, for elementary functions)

@J.N. In those cases you'll need to understand how that particular function behaves to find the sequences. And for that there is no formula or algorithm. What you'll need is practice.

Definition 1: $ \displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ is said to exist and equal $c\in\mathbb{R}$ if, for every $\varepsilon>0,\ \exists\ \delta>0$ such that
$$ 0<\vert x - x_0\vert<\delta \implies \vert f(x) - c \vert <\varepsilon.$$
Note that this does not require $c=f(x_0):$ this would be the definition of $f$ being continuous at $x=x_0.$
$$$$
Definition 2:
The limit of a sequence, $ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n,$ is said to exist and equal $a\in\mathbb{R}$ if, for every $\varepsilon>0,\ \exists\ N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$ n\geq N \implies \vert a_n - a \vert <\varepsilon.$$
$$$$
Definition 3:
$ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=+\infty,$ if, for every $r>0,\ \exists\ N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$ n\geq N \implies a_n \geq r.$$
And you want to use the following theorem:

If, for every sequence $a_n$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to
 +\infty}a_n = x_0\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ where $a_n \neq x_0$, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty} f(a_n)=c,$ then $\lim_{x\to
 x_0} f(x)=c$ also.

I will not prove this theorem, as you did not ask for a proof.
However, I will prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty} e^{-x}=0$ using the theorem.
To this end, suppose that $a_n$ is a sequence such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to
 +\infty}a_n = +\infty.$ We need to show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to
 +\infty}e^{-a_n}=0,$ for then, since the sequence $a_n$ was arbitrary, the theorem would tell us that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty} e^{-x}=0.$ So we proceed to this end. Let $\varepsilon>0.$ Since $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to
 +\infty}a_n = +\infty,$ for every $r>0,\ \exists\ N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$ n\geq N \implies a_n \geq r.$$
In particular, $\exists\ N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$ n\geq N \implies a_n \geq r:=\log\left(\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\right),$$
i.e.,
$$ 0< \vert e^{-a_n}-0\vert < \varepsilon\quad \forall\ n\geq N. $$
So I have "tried all the sequences $a_n$", although this is all a bit silly here, because it would have been just as easy (if not, slightly easier) to just prove that $\lim_{x\to +\infty} e^{-x}$ directly, although you would need a different definition to Definitions $1,2,3$ to know how to do this.

There is no way to show that it exists without having to "try" all sequences, this is baked into the definition.
If you think about it, taking an arbitrary sequence and then proving the limit of the image exists and is well-defined is simply the same as applying the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition for limits, just as you would expect it to be.
The sequential criteria generally is useful to show the limit does not exist. It helps to know the sequential criteria while proving certain theorems, as it may lead to more natural proofs.

What you write sounds correct. However, you actually can use OP's theorem to show that limits exist. I will post my answer shortly.

I never said that you could not use OP's theorem though, I just said it would essentially amount to using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition for limits. The sequences would just serve to make the argument slightly longer (but not any different). I look forward to your answer.
